# Code is compiling but its not giving correct volume

Tags: c++

How to correct this code, its not working properly. 
length and width is not getting the correct values.
I'm having problem where I declared Rectangle::get().

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle{
  protected:
    double length;
    double width;
  public:
    void setter(double len, double wid)
    {
      length = len;
      width = wid;
    }
    double get()
    {
      return length*width;
    }

};
class Block: public Rectangle{
  private:
    double heigth;
  public:
  void setter_h(double hei)
  {
    heigth = hei;
  }
  double get_1()
  {
    return(heigth * Rectangle::get());//this is the problem
  }
};


int main()
{
  double len, hei, wid;
  cout<<"Enter the length: ";
  cin>>len;
  cout<<"Enter the Width: ";
  cin>>wid;
  cout<<"Enter the H: ";
  cin>>hei;

  Rectangle R1;
  R1.setter(len,wid);
  cout<<"Area: " << R1.get();

  Block B1;
  B1.setter_h(hei);
  cout<<"Volume: "<< B1.get_1();
}
```

Can someone please help me???
im totaly confused because i  think i have written right code but its giving garbage value for volume.

Comment: You should do the B1.setter, because you inherited from the rectangle, you are setting the data on another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't set the width and length for `B1`. You should also call

```
B1.setter(len, wid);
```

before calling `B1.get_1()`.